# Symfony Finder not finding files that have double digit numbers

Tags: php, regex, symfony

I have files in a directory

```
singleProducts_1.json
singleProducts_2.json
....
singleProducts_9.json
singleProducts_10.json
singleProducts_11.json
....
singleProducts_20.json
```

On regex101.com I seem to have the correct regex to capture files from say 6 to 12, or anything from under 10 to over 10. E.g. this captures anything from 6 upwards:

```
singleProducts_([6-9]|[0-9][0-9]).json
```

However, when I use this in conjunction with Symfony's Finder, it doesn't find them. What is wrong with this code?

```
$products->files()
->name('singleProducts_([6-9]|[0-9][0-9]).json')
->in($productDirectory);
```

It should produce

```
singleProducts_6.json
singleProducts_7.json
singleProducts_8.json
....
singleProducts_20.json
```

Comment: If I read [this page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html), you could try using delimiters like a forward slash and escape the dot to match it literally: `->name('/singleProducts_([6-9]|[0-9][0-9])\.json/')`

Comment: Yes that works thanks